# Process id dismiss when ssh connect again

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, process

I have a VPS `DigitalOcean` and an `Ubuntu Droplet`. In order to execute a task background, I use `nohup` command.

```
 # nohup python patrol.py &
```

Everything works well but when I close ssh connection and connect it again, I find the process id does not exist.The python task sends a request to an api every 20 minutes.From the api server console, I find the process still works.**However from `ps` command  I can not find the process id**

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `cron`.... modify your python code to simply do the task and use `cron` as the timer by telling it execute every 20 minutes.... `crontab -e` ... then...  `*/20 * * * *    python patrol.py`

Comment: I use `time.sleep(60*20)` to do the task every 20 minutes. So is there any problem?

Comment: `ps -ef` or `ps aux`?

Comment: @ilkkachu Your save me. Thanks very much. Can you write your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps` by default shows only the processes running in the same terminal, so a process that got sent to the background after the SSH connection died, will not show.

As the manual says, use `ps -ef` or one of these ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)):

> To see every process on the system using standard syntax:
>
> ```
> ps -e
> ps -ef                            
> ps -eF
> ps -ely
> ```
>
> To see every process on the system using BSD syntax:
>
> ```
> ps ax
> ps axu
> ```

Though if all you want is to run something every 20 minutes, running it from `cron` would save you from having the restart the process if the system reboots, and would also run the future tasks even if a previous run crashed for some reason.